# How to copy the /system/media/audio from phone to PC

Tags: file-management

The `adb pull /system/media/audio` command works on one of my phones to copy the folder to my PC, it copies the folder's contents recursively.

However, on my other phone the USB connector is broken, and the phone cannot get a USB data connection. The phone is not rooted and it's impossible to root without losing data. The apps *FolderSync*, *ES File Explorer* and *ASTRO File Manager* can't see the */system* folder: they see */* as empty.

My plan was (1) to use a file manager to copy the contents of */system/media/audio* to */sdcard/audio*, and then (2) to use *FolderSync* to copy */sdcard/audio* to Google Drive. Step (1) doesn't work, I haven't found any app so far which is able to see */system*. Also running ADB over TCP would require rooting the phone, which is not possible (because I don't want to lose data and settings).

Is there a way to copy */system/media/audio* from this phone to my PC?

Answer (score 2):

What about using Termux and copy those files like this?

```
cp -R /system/media/audio /sdcard/system_audio
```

and then you can pull `system_audio` from your storage as usual.

For most ROMs, you'll want to grant storage permission tovTermux first:

```
termux-setup-storage
```

and tap "Grant".

Comment: I was getting `cp: ...: Permission denied` until I enabled the *Storage* permission on the Termux app on Android 9. Then the copy worked. If you update your answer with that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an FTP server. I used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.ftpserver). I set the login to anonymous, HOME directory to root (/) and started the server. I logged in to the server using my PC (used Linux; Windows natively supports FTP access too - try the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/88572/423702) from Ashok). If you get into issues in using your File explorer to access FTP server, then simply fire up your browser and access the URL directly. It would be like `ftp://IP_ADDRESS:PORT`. Make sure to remain within the same Wi-Fi.

At first, I logged in successfully (Code 200) but naturally didn't see anything in FTP server (an unprivileged user). But I edited the URL to directly jump into /system/ and it did load successfully, all without root too. My URL was `ftp://192.168.0.18:9999/system/`.